# Надо что бы pdf-файл был внутри exe

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

**Программа**: открывает лекцию, по окончании чтения лекции предлагает пройти тест. После теста выводит результат.

Проект написан в windows forms. Лекция в формате pdf. Открываю файл с помощью Adobe PDF Reader:

```
        string filePath = "C:\\Users\\q\\1.pdf";
        this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filePath);
        this.axAcroPDF1.src = filePath;
        this.axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
        this.axAcroPDF1.setView("FitH");
        this.axAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage");
        this.axAcroPDF1.Show();
```

**Проблема**: надо, чтобы pdf-файл был в проекте (внутри `.exe`), дабы его можно было бы прочитать только в программе.

Comment: Ну положите его в ресурсы, если ваш контрол умеет читать из стрима.

Comment: как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста? Использую VS 15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в меню Проект выберите пункт Свойства.
Перейдите на вкладку Ресурсы.
В панели инструментов Конструктора ресурсов укажите на Добавление ресурсов, щелкните стрелку, затем Добавить существующий файл.

Однако, скорее всего не будет поддерживаться загрузка из стрима( о чем и говорил Влад) 
**т.е. сказать**

```
this.axAcroPDF1.src=WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.1.pdf
```

**Не выйдет**. Тогда придется делать адский кастыль, сохранять куда-нибудь в темп через FileStream,

```
File.WriteAllBytes("1.pdf", MyResources.1.pdf);
```

а затем уже открывать, как с диска.

```
        string filePath = "1.pdf";
        this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filePath);
        this.axAcroPDF1.src = filePath;
        this.axAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
        this.axAcroPDF1.setView("FitH");
        this.axAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage");
        this.axAcroPDF1.Show();
```

После окончания чтения зачищать директорию...

`if(File.Exists(filePath))File.Delete(filePath);`

Как всегда, скорее всего ошибаюсь и есть лучший путь...

Comment: Добавил файл в ресурсы (спасибо, теперь буду знать как добавлять). И сразу появился вопрос: в свойствах этого ресурса есть пункт "Действие при сборке", тут что надо указывать?

Comment: **второе**: при попытке вставить  строчку 'System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("1.pdf", MyResources.1.pdf);' не знает что такое MyResources. Как его добавить?

Comment: посмотрите на первый путь, там точнее будет путь до ресурсов: WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("1.pdf", Properties.Resources._1);` - получилась такая строчка. Почему "_1"? после этой строчки пдфка не открывается(

Comment: ресурсы если не называть, так именуются(_НазваниеФайла) так, что всё нормально :)

Comment: а есть еще предположение как можно открыть файл, или как довести этот метод до победного? Сама лекция есть в формате word(т.е. есть возможность сохранить в разных форматах). Если можно как то по другому открыть, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: оу да методов много, теоретически можно показывать и pdf в браузерном компоненте, можно https://habrahabr.ru/post/112707/ найти другой pdf компонтент(со стримом). Можно с помощью опенофиса брать данные из ворд файла и выводить... Подумать надо, что лучше. Для сохранности лекций, теоретически можно было бы перевести все в картинку, перед выводом на экран, а потом их листать... Хотя файнридер всё-ровно сделает свое дело.

Comment: боюсь вышесказанное даст больше вопросов чем ответов, лучше углубитесь в pdf показание из ресурсового файла.

Comment: Кстати this.axAcroPDF1.src =Properties.Resources._1 не получилось сделать?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему нужно отказаться от акробата и показывать pdf непосредственно в своей программе с помощью какого-нибудь PdfViewer'a - движка просмотра pdf.
Я рекомендую гугловский Pdfium. Для .Net существуют обертки этого движка. Как платные так и бесплатные. Мы пользуем платный, для нашей задачи, а для вашей вполне и бесплатный может подойти. Pvginkel - исходники на гитхабе есть. Вообще загугли Pdfium PdfViewer

Comment: «Вообще загугли» — это плохой совет, гугл приводит назад на StackOverflow. Вы бы лучше привели пример кода.